# How to ignore if textarea exists but add the last row w/ textarea if it doesn't exists? (not every time when a button is clicked)

Tags: jquery

When a button is clicked, the script will check to see if the textarea exists or not.  If it exists then ignore.  If it doesn't exists, I want it to add a last row w/ new textarea only once.  But when I do this, it kept adding rows w/ repeating textarea.  Thanks.

```
<table class='DelTable'>
 <tbody>
  <tr id='DelData'><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='delmsg'>5</td><tr>
  <tr><td>&#160;</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<input type='button' value='test' onclick='AddMe()' />

<script type='text/javascript">
function AddMe()
{
    $('table.DelTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>Reasons: <textarea id='#MeBox' /></td></tr><tr><td> </td><tr>')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the ID :

(I also corrected the ID)

```
function AddMe()
{
    if ($('#MeBox').length) {
        return; // we already have one
    }

    $('table.DelTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>Reasons: <textarea id="MeBox" /></td></tr><tr><td> </td><tr>');
}
```

Comment: Nice....  Thanks...   (Still waiting for 5 minutes to be up to click the Accepted Answer)...

Answer (score 1):

what u are looking for i think.. is..

```
if($("#MeBox").length > 0){
//IGNORE
}else{
//add your textarea
```

}